# Using vue with javaee container (wildfly) in a multi page application

Tags: jakarta-ee, vue.js, controller, mapping

we have a matured JavaEE application which is built with JSF and EJB. For several reasons we want to get rid of JSF (blocking js calls, session size, templating etc). Our selected approach  is to either replace xhtml pages completely with jsps, that create vue templates, or something similar.

The problem we encounter: how to provide url mapping to some kind of controller and connect it to a new page with injected beans. In the classic JSF approach the xhtml page is called, which declares beans it wants to access, which are then injected by the framework. Now we need something else which can be injected with the CDI Beans, read information needed for the rendering and put the json objects along with the vue templates into resulting markup, allowing the browser to render the page swiftly (especially without a need to load all required data via REST resources after the page has been rendered).

I possible approach would be to create a servlet for every url, which uses injected beans, puts data in request scope and forwards to the jsp with markup. But servlet seems to be so 2003...

So we are searching for a small framework which is able to work with CDI injection and allow some jsp-like rendering. Something like spring-mvc for cdi.

Is anyone aware of such a framework? Maybe there is a better approach to what we are trying to achieve?

Kind regards
Leon